# MySQL Users and All Privileges

Tags: mysql, web-applications, user-accounts, sql-grant

Ok, I'm trying to add a user to a MySQL database. This user should be able to add other users to the database it has privileges for. So I did this:

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON thedbname.* TO 'topuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

However, I this user cannot add users. Is that because I only gave them 'all' for a single database? The permissions show up as 'N' when I view them whereas if I remove the database name they show as 'Y'.

I want 'topuser' to be able to run this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON thedbname.* TO 'seconduser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

They do not need to add users to other databases, hence my attempts here.

This is for a web app where users provide a username and password to access a database so that a password is not stored in the code. Other solutions welcomed though!

Answer (score 1):

You have to GRANT the "grant to other privilege". The manual of the GRANT is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).

MySQL to include only basic privileges in the ALL, if you take a close look at the documentation it says all is :

```
Grant all privileges at specified access level except GRANT OPTION
```

so you should grant the "grant option" to your top user :

```
GRANT GRANT OPTION ON thedbname.* TO 'topuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

Comment: Tried that already but with "Error code 1410, SQL state 42000: You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT" error.

Comment: do you have root access to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE 'admin';
INSERT INTO mysql.user (host, user, password) VALUES ('localhost', 'admin', 'portal01');
INSERT INTO mysql.user (host, user, password) VALUES ('%', 'admin', 'portal01');
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'portal01' WITH GRANT OPTION;sudo 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'portal01' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT * FROM mysql.user ORDER BY user;
```

Comment: Sure, you can do it with script. This is just raw code to give you the necessary information. I have copies a mysql.user table from one server to another when root information is lost.  There is more than one way to skin a cat.